# How to disable Golang unused function error?

Tags: go, go-staticcheck

I'm trying to debug a program by commenting out a function and seeing how this affects the result. BUT commenting out this function means that it is unused which results in Go throwing an "unused function" error. How do I temporarily disable this error so that I can debug my program without having to re-write my entire program just to debug a small part?

I know that unused imports and variables can be ignored (detailed below), but can't find anything about ignoring unused functions.

To disable/ignore the unused **import** error simply prepend an `_` to the package name.

```
 import (
   "fmt" // how you normally import packages
   _"log" // how you import packages and ignore the unused import error
)
```

To disable/ignore an unused **variable** you can re-name the variable `_`.

```
myvar, _ := some_function()
```

But how do you ignore an unused **function**?

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxOGz.png) of the error message I'm getting.

Comment: Unused functions are legal in Go programs. The Go compiler does report unused function errors.   Perhaps your IDE or a lint tool are reporting the problem.   The following statement might silence the warning:  `var _ = some_function`.

Comment: @just_another_question, don't paraphrase or abridge error messages.  Post them verbatim, as text.  In this case it's clear you've misrepresented your error message

Comment: @DanielFarrell I've added a screenshot. It says "func task is unused".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like you are using Go Staticcheck (or your IDE is). If you really need to disable this warning for whatever reason, you can follow the [Staticcheck documentation](https://staticcheck.io/docs/configuration/#ignoring-problems). A comment like this should do it:

```golang
//lint:ignore U1000 Ignore unused function temporarily for debugging
```

Comment: Do you know if I can ignore U1000 checks for all files in a project? I read the staticcheck doc but it seems it only supports adding this lint:ignore line in code files, not in the staticcheck.conf file.